# Tensors and suffix notation

Tags: matrices, tensors

I'm just looking for an explanation as to why $R_{ip}R_{iq} = \delta_{ij}$ $\\ $ Here R is a rotation, and is orthogonal, and $det(R) = 0$. 
One of the explanations I've seen is that $R_{ip}R_{jp} = (RR^T)_{ij}$, but I don't really understand that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R_{ip}R_{iq}= \delta_{pq}$ (notice that the indices on the Kronecker delta should be $pq$) can be shown in just a few steps:

$$\begin{align}R_{ip}R_{iq} &= R_{pi}^TR_{iq} &\text{(by definition of transpose)} \\ &= [R^TR]_{pq} &\text{(by definition of matrix products)} \\ &= [I]_{pq} &\text{(by definition of orthogonal matrices)} \\ &= \delta_{pq} &\text{(by definition of the Kronecker delta)}\end{align}$$